# Missing classes issue on a xml file?

Tags: android

The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.design.internal.NavigationView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

Comment: As you answered try to **clean** and **rebuild** project.

Comment: yes i have try but that issue also same.can't solve

Comment: Did you define the design support library as a dependency? Show us the build.gradle file.

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

Answer (score 3):

```
android.support.design.internal.NavigationView
```

Package name itself telling that it is inside **internal** package, and you are not supposed to use it directly.

Maybe what you need is something like this in your XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/navigation"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```